# use different javascript based on date

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to use a different set of javascripts based on the date.

this is the script elements in body my html page

```
<script src="snow.js"></script>


<script src="petals1.js"></script>
<script src="petals2.js"></script>
<script src="petals3.js"></script>
<script src="petals4.js"></script>


<script src="leaves1.js"></script>
<script src="leaves2.js"></script>
```

they all load when the page is opened so for now i have them commented out, but i don't want to have to manually edit the pages to comment/uncomment scripts throughout the year. How can i use the petal scripts in spring months, leaves in fall, snow in winter automatically?

I have access to client side scripts like js (obviously) and php for server side

Comment: wrap them in php conditional(s) that check applicable dates

Comment: Depending on the effects and functionality of the scripts, it may be similarly easy to have one JavaScript function to load the relevant assets and perform manipulations; but I tend to agree with Charlietfl that this is likely better done server side.

Comment: problem is i didnt write the js files and im not to good at js. so i cant combine them or do much more then editing variables in them. thats why im looking for some php to load the ready made scripts for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps better done on PHP side. Very roughly:

```
// get today's date
$today = new DateTime();

// get the season dates
$spring = new DateTime('March 20');
$summer = new DateTime('June 20');
$fall = new DateTime('September 22');
$winter = new DateTime('December 21');

switch(true) {
    case $today >= $fall && $today < $winter:
        echo '<script src="leaves.js"></script>';
        break;
    case $today >= $winter && $today < $spring:
        echo '<script src="snow.js"></script>';
        break;
    case $today >= $spring && $today < $summer:
        echo '<script type="petals.js"></script>';
        break;

   default:
        echo 'Summer.';
```

}

Comment: I got an error      "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in \files\Falling\index.php on line 18"    line 18 of my file is    "$spring = new DateTime('March 20');"

Comment: what is your line 18?

Comment: oh, i forgot, have had something extra, try now.

Comment: Printed Summer on my screen from the default: echo at the end, didnt load any of the scripts on to the page.

Comment: i put all the script echos in the default and they all print into the page, but the switching isnt working.

Comment: What do you mean switching isn't working? You always have all the scripts?

Comment: none, with the above php it just prints summer. on my page.